# Is there a suggested list of values for Laravel's APP_ENV variable (found in the .env file)?

Tags: laravel

I can't seem to find any sort of official list of the `APP_ENV` variable in the `.env` file. In practice I've used `local`, `dev`, `development`, `staging`, and `production`. And I feel like this works okay... and I've even seen some of these used by other prominent Laravel developers. However I'd feel much more confident if there was a standard. Is there a PSR standard that defines environment names? Or maybe some Laravel documentation I'm missing?

Comment: Digging in the source the only three that seem having some effects are `local`,  `production` and `testing`, I agree that the documentation is lacking.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

As far as I know, only `local`, `testing` and `production` are standard, because the [`Illuminate/Foundation/Application`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L517) class contains the methods `isLocal()`, `runningUnitTests()` and `isProduction()` for checking them.

Comment: BTW isLocal() and isProduction() are declared but never used, I searched from the root in a fresh laravel project.

Comment: It seems they're meant for use with `app()->isLocal()`.

Comment: `testing` should only be used for unit tests. Packages like laravel-debugbar disable themselves on testing.

Answer (score 3):

We use `local`/`development`/`staging`/`production`.